# Create a relative path mixin with LESS

Tags: css, less

I have a bunch of svg's I am placing as background images. I'm looking for a way to create a partial path with a variable and then pass just the file name into my mixin. Something like this:

```
@url: "url('../images/icons/_mm/";
.bg(@fileName){
background-image:@url @fileName;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't concatenate correctly. When I pass in an argument like this:

```
.mmWrap{
.bg('swoosh.svg');
}
```

the resulting css is this:

```
.mmWrap {
  background-image: "url('../images/icons/_mm/" 'swoosh.svg';
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

...a mess. And the LESS compiler throws an error if I try to pass the argument without quotes. I know the answer may involve the escape ~ string, but I'm all out of ideas. Can anyone help out here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

To do something like that you'd have to resort to string interpolation..

```
@image_dir: '../images/';

.bg(@filename) {
    background-image: url('@{image_dir}@{filename}');
}
```

This is the only way I know of using LESS. Hope this helps!

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks so much! That's a real time-saver!